# How to call cmd from C# application to generate nsis installer?

Tags: c#, command-prompt, nsis

I am trying to call a command prompt from a C# application and then the command prompt will run an argument to generate a nsis installer.

So this is the function inside the C# application which generate the installer:

```
    private bool GenerateInstaller(string pStrVersion)
    {
        bool IsSuccess = false;

        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Installer version: " + pStrVersion);

        if(pStrVersion == "PRO")
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe"" ""Z:\Project\BuildArea\workspace\installer\Setup_PRO.nsi""";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("argument: " + startInfo.Arguments);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            IsSuccess = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe"" ""Z:\Project\BuildArea\workspace\installer\Setup_STD.nsi""";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("argument: " + startInfo.Arguments);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            IsSuccess = true;
        }

        return IsSuccess;
    }
```

The problem is when I try to run the C# app, it doesn't generate the installer.
At the first time, I thought the string argument is wrong. So, I opened a new command prompt and try to run the argument directly and it works.

Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you start makensis.exe directly?

```
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"Z:\Project\BuildArea\workspace\installer\Setup_PRO.nsi";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```